# Where is the Linux socket implementation?

Tags: linux

In C programs, in order to use sockets, we need to include:

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
```

I have searched for the `socket.c` file (the implementation of `<sys/socket.h>`) but didn't found it (`find -iname "socket.c*"`)

1. Where can I find the Linux socket implementation?
2. Can I modify this file and change this implementation?

Comment: The socket implementation is part of the glibc runtime library. You need to install the sources of that library. Normally the source files are not installed on a system, since they are not required for the operation of the system.

Comment: You certainly can change the implementation of that file, sure. To use the result you then have to recompile the resulting library. Take care however not to ruin your running system. So just compile the library but do not install the result at first. Instead link some programs to the compiled library and test if things work as expected. You can do that by either statically linking the program against your library or by altering the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable of the process calling those programs.

Comment: After download the glibc source (sudo apt-get install glibc-source) and search for socket.c (/usr/src/glibc) still can't find the socket implementation

Comment: Indeed, I do have to apologize: the socket _function_ in the glibc library is only a wrapper around the kernel function which is implemented in the kernel sources, obviously. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: What do you hope to achieve in changing the implementation in the libc or kernel?

Comment: And what part of "the socket implementation" are you planning on changing? It's a large enough feature that it isn't all in one place.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The header file  contains declarations for socket-related system calls. To start diving into the implementation, please consider referring to `net/socket.c` file in the [Linux source tree](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/socket.c).

Regarding changing the implementation - Linux is an open-source software product distributed under the terms of [GNU GPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html). If you'll spend quite some time to understand how to re-build the kernel from scratch, you'll be able to apply any changes you want to the kernel and deploy it to your local machines (at your own risk of course).

Answer (score 3):

`socket()` implementation is in `net/socket.c` in the linux kernel sources

```c
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(socket, int, family, int, type, int, protocol)
```

You can modify this file an the implementation.