# Location of accept() function in socket.h

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, kernel

I'm looking for the accept() function in socket.h, so I can modify it and recompile the Linux kernel.
However, I was able to find the 'extern' functions in socket.h, without the actual code:

```
extern int accept (int __fd, __SOCKADDR_ARG __addr,
                   socklen_t *__restrict __addr_len);

#ifdef __USE_GNU
/* Similar to 'accept' but takes an additional parameter to specify flags.

   This function is a cancellation point and therefore not marked with
   __THROW.  */
extern int accept4 (int __fd, __SOCKADDR_ARG __addr,
                    socklen_t *__restrict __addr_len, int __flags);
#endif
```

Can someone tell me where to find the actual code for these networking functions, so I can modify and recompile them?

Comment: [linux/net/socket.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/45dfb8a5659ad286c28fa59008271dbc4e5e3f2d/net/socket.c#L1777)

Comment: I'm pulling out zero results for any such file:  find / -name "socket.c"

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850611/where-is-the-linux-socket-implementation

Comment: @ugp The linux kernel source code is not usually part of your system. You need to download it yourself. For example from [here](https://www.kernel.org/). Some more info: [How do I get the kernel source code?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159833/how-do-i-get-the-kernel-source-code). If that's not already clear to you then you may need to do more research before attempting to modify, build and load the linux kernel.

Comment: Thanks! I followed the instructions for apt-get install glibc-source and had the debian source code extracted.  However on going to accept.c, this was all that was there:      int
accept (int fd, __SOCKADDR_ARG addr, socklen_t *addr_len)
{
  __set_errno (ENOSYS);
  return -1;
}
libc_hidden_def (accept)


stub_warning (accept) .  Where is the actual implementation of the accept function?

Comment: glibc is not the kernel...

Comment: Of course, it's the Linux source code, isn't it?  I want to modify and recompile to another kernel...Am I on the right track?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the Linux socket implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850611/where-is-the-linux-socket-implementation)

Comment: You seem confused. Are you trying to recompile the user library or the Linux kernel? Glibc is the user library and not the kernel. As you have found it does very little. It just invokes the system call which then goes into the kernel. If you want to change the accept behaviour you need to change the kernel. Looking at glibc code will not help with that. I already gave you the links for the kernel. Don't know why you didn't use that and went to the glibc code instead.

Comment: This is what I want to do: I want to print out every connection that comes in using accept() or bind().  I want to do it as a default, so every user and every connection is logged automatically right at the system call level.  If I can modify a header file, that's fine, if not, let me know if I can modify the kernel itself.

Comment: @ugp you would have to modify the kernel itself. Otherwise, you could just use a `pcap` library to monitor the system for connections and log them as needed, without modifying the system itself. Also, `bind()` does not make connections, perhaps you meant `connect()` instead?

Comment: Sure. I want to be able to dump messages and write specific content when I receive certain packets.  How would I proceed to modify the kernel, especially the socket sys calls?